# My DNS server has changed to AWS lightsail, yet the site points to old hosting service

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-lightsail

I created an instance of lightsail (LAMP), and in namecheap I changed my DNS server.
The attached images list the modifications I made and whether they have actually changed. Yet my site keeps pointing towards the old server!!! I have spent hours on it today. Would appreciate any help.

: The records I added in lightsail

[image: The records I added in lightsail]

The updated name servers
[image: The updated name servers]

The updated A records

[image: The updated A records]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely TTLs that already existed for the DNS record that are cached either on your local network or in the browser.

[This article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-flush-dns-cache) explains how to clear the network cache depending on your OS.

In addition some browsers also cache DNS, you should be able to test your site by attempting to access it either in another browser or in incognito (depending on browser).

I can confirm I can connect to a host on the IP address you specified in the question returning a `200` status.

Comment: I did as you said, waited nearly 12 hours. Didn't work. I believe when you connect to ip, its my old host. If you can go to EARNchart.com/2index.html then its old host as this file is not there in New server.

Comment: When you run `DIG earnchart.com` from your local machine what does it return?